# Google sheets custom function not working with an array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am making a custom function for google sheets called `MODINVERSE()` which takes a multiplier and a modifier to find its modular multiplicative inverse. I got it to work if you plug in a single value, but I want it to work for an array input. This means if I put in an array such as `MODINVERSE(A1:A3,X)` its output would be an array that lists the modular multiplicative inverse for each of the three values in the example array of `A1:A3`.

Script:

```
function MODINVERSE(multiplier, modifier) {
  var output = [];
  
  if (modifier <= 1){
    output.push([0])
  } else {
    if (multiplier == 0) {
      output.push([0])
    } else {
      for (var X = 1; X < modifier; X++) {
        if (((multiplier % modifier) * (X % modifier)) % modifier == 1) {
         output.push([X])
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: You example does not help to explain your question as it does not include any reference to an array parameter.  And what does it mean to return an array to a single cell.

Comment: @Cooper let me rephrase that, I meant that I want to be able to have a range of values as an input and a range of those values' modular multiplicative inverses as an output. I want it to return the range of values through multiple cells, but I was thinking that I could accomplish that with a simple `=ARRAYFORMULA()` with my function inside.

Comment: In your example what does, your Values on A1:A3, does it show like this "7,3" as multiplier and modifier respectively? and on your edited parameters for function what does  the X represent. Yes you can accomplish that on as using array formula, but if you are looking to built it in and what my assumptions above are correct you are missing the range parameter where this formula will be used.

Comment: Custom Functions cannot change the values of other cells, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_services

Comment: @Babanana the X represents the modifier so like the same as the second value in the `MOD()` function and `A1:A3` is my example for the range of values I want to plug in, so it would be like cells 1-3 of the "A" column.

Comment: Also what do you mean by I am missing the "range parameter" I am quite new to this and I'm not very familiar with a lot of these terms.

Comment: @Collin So what I mean is that you are missing a range parameter, in order for you to process values within a range. I.E: A1:A3. I want to clarify parts of your desired custom functions. `MODINVERSE(range, modifier)`, where range is I assume would be the multiplier and modifier will be something constant from a cell or do you want it to change as your custom function goes down the range?

Comment: i think itll be fine staying the same

Comment: if i use the range parameter would it still work for only 1 value aswell?

Comment: @Babanana so im still confused, would it be as simple as replacing all the references to `multiplier` with `range`?

Comment: So basically on your Apps Script code you are not iterating all the items on your range, that is what is missing. That is the reason why you are not getting the array as output as the formula is just for one. Let me compose an answer that will take consideration everything you have shared on this post and highlight the part of iterating through out the range of your values.

Comment: @Collin If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253961/discussion-between-babanana-and-collin-dehmer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Iterate Formula Through a range.

What you are missing is iterating through the range. As shown in my example below. Despite our conversation I might be missing something as we don't have a reproducible example. Please feel free to use this example to get your desired output.

### Sample Code:

```
function MODINVERSE(range, modifier) {
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YourSheetName"); //Please edit based on your sheet name
var rangeToProcess = sheet.getRange(range); // it is for getting the range values to process along with getting how many times the formula will be used.
var multiplier = rangeToProcess.getValues();
var output = [];
for(i = 0; i< multiplier.length;i++ ){ // This is the Part where it is going to loop through your range
  if (modifier <= 1){ // just copied your logic here with minimal edit and using the index if where the loop is
    output.push([0])
  } else {
    if (multiplier[i] == 0) {
      output.push([0])
    } else {
      for (var y = 1; y < modifier; y++) {
        if (((multiplier[i] % modifier) * (y % modifier)) % modifier == 1) {
         output.push([y])
        }
      }
    }
  }
 

} return output;}
```

Using this custom function please take note that you have to use this format for your formula. `=MODINVERSE("A1:A3",5)` There should be a quotation mark for your range to be parsed as string, your modifier should be an int, if it is not in and a range please use the code as reference and use a getValue() function to assign it to a variable.

### Reference:

[getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)